# Tensorflow serving trained model saved with saved_model

Tags: tensorflow

I find tf.saved_model documentation not clear, is there any valuable resources how to read trained model within other session?

Answer (score 0):

It's as easy as:

```
# Clear the default graph if any
tf.reset_default_graph()
# Create a saver/loader object
loader = tf.train.Saver()
# Build the same graph architecture (Easiest to do with a class)
model = YourModel()
# Create a session
with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Initialize the variables in the graph
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    # Restore the learned weights from a saved checkpoint
    loader.restore(sess, path_to_checkpoint_dir)
```